# Using ShareKit with Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, sharekit

My iPhone application is developed using Xcode 5. I want to use ShareKit library in order to share images and urls from my application. The problem is, that ShareKit seems to be incompatible with Xcode 5 (thought is says it is).

Attached screenshot to illustrate my problem:

[image]

Any help (or alternative solution for sharing images and URLs) will be greatly welcome.

Comment: This is really not a problem with Xcode.

Comment: I'm using sharekit with xcode 5. Are you sure you completely followed their integration guide?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you both are referring to an obsolete, long time abandoned version of ShareKit. Check [ShareKit 2](https://github.com/sharekit/sharekit). For easiest installation I recommend Cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions [here](http://getsharekit.com/install/)? 
(It seems like you've added objc-class.h that has no use)

Also, consider using the **native** sharing class UIActivityViewController for sharing purposes.